# Responsive table - effect on the datepicker

Tags: css, datatable, responsive-design, css-tables

I'm using the following example to make my DataTable responsive.
Everything works fine, except for the cells containing a jQuery datepicker.

**UPDATE**: working example:

[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w7b5jjy8)

CSS used:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: #5e5d52;
}

a {
  color: #337aa8;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #4b8ab2;
}

.container {
  margin: 5% 3%;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .container {
    margin: 2%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 75em) {
  .container {
    margin: 2em auto;
    max-width: 75em;
  }
}

.responsive-table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table {
    font-size: .9em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .responsive-table {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
.responsive-table thead {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table thead {
    position: relative;
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
.responsive-table thead th {
  background-color: #1d96b2;
  border: 1px solid #1d96b2;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.responsive-table thead th:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}
.responsive-table tbody,
.responsive-table tr,
.responsive-table th,
.responsive-table td {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tr {
    display: table-row;
  }
}
.responsive-table th,
.responsive-table td {
  padding: .5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .responsive-table th,
  .responsive-table td {
    padding: .75em .5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table th,
  .responsive-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .responsive-table th,
  .responsive-table td {
    padding: .75em .5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 75em) {
  .responsive-table th,
  .responsive-table td {
    padding: .75em;
  }
}
.responsive-table caption {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table caption {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
.responsive-table tfoot {
  font-size: .8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .responsive-table tfoot {
    font-size: .9em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody tr {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #1d96b2;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody tr {
    display: table-row;
    border-width: 1px;
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: rgba(94, 93, 82, 0.1);
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody th[scope="row"] {
  background-color: #1d96b2;
  color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody th[scope="row"] {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #5e5d52;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody td {
  text-align: right;
}
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .responsive-table tbody td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1d96b2;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody td {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody td[data-type=currency] {
  text-align: right;
}
.responsive-table tbody td[data-title]:before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  float: left;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: rgba(94, 93, 82, 0.75);
}
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .responsive-table tbody td[data-title]:before {
    font-size: .9em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody td[data-title]:before {
    content: none;
  }
}
```

This also affects the datepicker and changes its style, i.e. change each row into a vertical list. I would like to keep my default datepicker style on all devices. How could I cancel the css behaviour for the cells containing the datepicker div?

Comment: If you cancel the vertical listing behavior for your datepicker then how are you planning to display it?

Comment: where is the datepicker?

Comment: @Reddy, so, with this CSS style, I have enough space for each cell on a mobile device (the whole width of the device). Therefore, I can show the datepicker on a mobile device as it looks on a desktop device (as a square)

Comment: @silviagreen: the last cell of each row contains a div, which will represent the datepicker.

Comment: @towi_parallelism I'm sorry, but I still cannot see any div at the end of each row in the codepen

Comment: @silviagreen, uh sorry! that's not my example.. It's the CSS I used in my code. Each row in the table is created dynamically in JavaScript. does it really matter? Do you want to suggest something like `td:nth-child(4)`?

Comment: No, honestly without a working code snippet I am not able to solve the problem

Comment: Yes, @towi_parallelism I think you have to add a Fiddle for better understanding and to get help.

Comment: @silviagreen, Okay, sorry about the confusion. Please see this link: https://jsfiddle.net/w7b5jjy8/

Comment: @Reddy please see the working example

Comment: Yes, I found the issue, lemme post my answer

Comment: Place your DateTimepicker Css below to this respnsive table css file in the referene page.. And let me know if the issue is fixed

Comment: @Reddy, I copied the whole, jquery-ui.css I was using after that https://jsfiddle.net/w7b5jjy8/2/ Didn't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best I could do: I simply rewrote the table css rules so they apply only to direct children, using the `>`.

**Update**: I mix my code with your original code using media query to apply mobile rules only when screen size is reduced and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w7b5jjy8/11/) is the result. As you can see, it works both in desktop and mobile mode.

The key is to apply the following rule only in desktop:

```
.responsive-table tbody,
.responsive-table tr,
.responsive-table th,
.responsive-table td {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

[fiddle with jquery ui](https://jsfiddle.net/w7b5jjy8/6/)

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  });
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: #5e5d52;
}

a {
  color: #337aa8;
}
a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #4b8ab2;
}

.container {
  margin: 5% 3%;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .container {
    margin: 2%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 75em) {
  .container {
    margin: 2em auto;
    max-width: 75em;
  }
}

.responsive-table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table {
    font-size: .9em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .responsive-table {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
.responsive-table thead {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table thead {
    position: relative;
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
.responsive-table thead th {
  background-color: #1d96b2;
  border: 1px solid #1d96b2;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.responsive-table thead th:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
.responsive-table tbody,
.responsive-table tr,
.responsive-table th,
.responsive-table td {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
}
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tr {
    display: table-row;
  }
}
.responsive-table th,
.responsive-table td {
  padding: .5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .responsive-table th,
  .responsive-table td {
    padding: .75em .5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table th,
  .responsive-table td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: .5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .responsive-table th,
  .responsive-table td {
    padding: .75em .5em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 75em) {
  .responsive-table th,
  .responsive-table td {
    padding: .75em;
  }
}
.responsive-table caption {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table caption {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
.responsive-table tfoot {
  font-size: .8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .responsive-table tfoot {
    font-size: .9em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody tr {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #1d96b2;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody tr {
    display: table-row;
    border-width: 1px;
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: rgba(94, 93, 82, 0.1);
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody th[scope="row"] {
  background-color: #1d96b2;
  color: white;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody th[scope="row"] {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #5e5d52;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody td {
  text-align: right;
}
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .responsive-table tbody td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1d96b2;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody td {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.responsive-table tbody td[data-type=currency] {
  text-align: right;
}
.responsive-table tbody td[data-title]:before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  float: left;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: rgba(94, 93, 82, 0.75);
}
@media (min-width: 30em) {
  .responsive-table tbody td[data-title]:before {
    font-size: .9em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .responsive-table tbody td[data-title]:before {
    content: none;
  }
}



@media (max-width: 767px){
  .responsive-table > thead {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-table > thead > th {
  background-color: #1d96b2;
  border: 1px solid #1d96b2;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.responsive-table > thead > th:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}
.responsive-table > tbody,
.responsive-table > tbody > tr, .responsive-table > thead > tr,
.responsive-table > tbody > tr > th, .responsive-table > thead > tr > th,
.responsive-table > tbody > tr > td, .responsive-table > thead > tr > td {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
}

.responsive-table > tbody > tr > th, .responsive-table > thead > tr > th,
.responsive-table > tbody > tr > td, .responsive-table > thead > tr > td {
  padding: .5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.responsive-table > tfoot {
  font-size: .8em;
  font-style: italic;
}

.responsive-table > tbody  tr {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #1d96b2;
}

.responsive-table > tbody  tr:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.responsive-table > tbody  th[scope="row"] {
  background-color: #1d96b2;
  color: white;
}

.responsive-table > tbody tr td {
  text-align: right;
}

.responsive-table tbody td[data-type=currency] {
  text-align: right;
}
.responsive-table tbody td[data-title]:before {
  content: attr(data-title);
  float: left;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: rgba(94, 93, 82, 0.75);
}

body .ui-datepicker-calendar thead{
  position: relative;
}


}
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
<div class="container">
  <table class="responsive-table">
    <caption>Top 10 Grossing Animated Films of All Time</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Film Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Released</th>
        <th scope="col">Studio</th>
        <th scope="col">Worldwide Gross</th>
        <th scope="col">Domestic Gross</th>
        <th scope="col">Foreign Gross</th>
        <th scope="col">Budget</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="7">Sources: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_animated_films" rel="external">Wikipedia</a> &amp; <a href="http://www.boxofficemojo.com/genres/chart/?id=animation.htm" rel="external">Box Office Mojo</a>. Data is current as of September 1, 2015.</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Frozen</th>
        <td data-title="Released">2013</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Disney</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$1,279,852,693</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$400,738,009 </td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$873,481,000</td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency"><div id="datepicker1">
        
        </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Toy Story 3</th>
        <td data-title="Released">2010</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Disney Pixar</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$1,063,171,911</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$415,004,880</td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$648,167,031</td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency">$200,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Minions</th>
        <td data-title="Released">2015</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Universal</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$1,018,901,000</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$324,755,670</td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$694,100,000 </td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency">$74,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">The Lion King</th>
        <td data-title="Released">1994</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Disney</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$987,483,777</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$422,783,777</td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$564,700,000</td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency">$45,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Despicable Me 2</th>
        <td data-title="Released">2013</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Universal</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$970,761,885</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$368,061,265</td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$602,700,620</td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency">$76,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Finding Nemo</th>
        <td data-title="Released">2003</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Pixar</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$936,743,261</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$380,843,261</td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$555,900,000</td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency">$94,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Shrek 2</th>
        <td data-title="Released">2004</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Dreamworks</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$919,838,758</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$441,226,247</td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$478,612,511</td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency">$150,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Ice Age: Dawn of the Dinosaurs</th>
        <td data-title="Released">2009</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Fox</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$886,686,817</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$196,573,705</td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$690,113,112 </td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency">$90,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Ice Age: Continental Drift</th>
        <td data-title="Released">2012</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Fox</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$877,244,782</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$161,321,843</td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$715,922,939</td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency">$95,000,000</td>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Shrek the Third</th>
        <td data-title="Released">2007</td>
        <td data-title="Studio">Dreamworks</td>
        <td data-title="Worldwide Gross" data-type="currency">$798,958,162</td>
        <td data-title="Domestic Gross" data-type="currency">$322,719,944</td>
        <td data-title="Foreign Gross" data-type="currency">$476,238,218</td>
        <td data-title="Budget" data-type="currency">$160,000,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: lol this is what I am currently doing, exact same thing!! But I still didnt get it to work

Comment: I will not post my asnwer anyways now, Dont wanna get blamed as copied . +1 for you

Comment: Thanks to both of you, but why is it ruining the layout on the desktop device? The one you posted with jquiery-ui is great for mobile-devices, but not for the dektop..

Comment: @towi_parallelism I have corrected my answer, now it works well in desktop too (without using jquery ui css)